# Setup eclipse to validate firefox addon-sdk libraries

Tags: javascript, eclipse, firefox-addon-sdk

Is there a way to configure `Eclipse` to be aware of the `firefox` `addon-sdk` libraries .. in such a way that if errors exist on api methods they are underlined like normal javascript errors?

Simple test using [self](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Add-ons/SDK/High-Level_APIs/self#data.url%28name%29) api from `addon-sdk` ..

```
var data = require("sdk/self").data;

exports.get = function(content) {
  return data.url(content);
}
```

If I remove `content` from `data.url()` there is no error or warning in my IDE, instead I only see the error at runtime, which seems pretty late ..

```
var data = require("sdk/self").data;

    exports.get = function(content) {
      return data.url();
    }
```